# 100% View Height and Width div with Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a little new to javascript scrolling effects, but I have a project due that requires a 100% vh and width div tag below the menu, but will not stay in the same position and will be scrolled up. I'm not great at explaining this, so here is a template site that illustrates my idea:
[Rhythm - Multipurpose Theme Template Preview](http://rhythm.bestlooker.pro/mp-index.html)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You might want to check out scroll events to detect when the user scrolls and react appropriately. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (SO) (and all of Stack Exchange (SE)) *must be* self-contained. The goal of SO/SE is to create a repository of questions and answers which are valuable to *future* visitors. Questions which *require* information from off-site/off-page resources are useless once those resources change or die. Any questions where such a resource is *required* to understand the question should be closed as "needs details of clarity", or other appropriate reason. A link to a website might be beneficial *in addition to information (e.g. code) **in the question itself***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear but I guess I understood it.

The navigation is fixed. Two main attributes are line-height and background-color, which is transparent.

If offsetTop != 0(if user scrolled) class is added which has line-height attribute (possibly ~ 20% less) and background-color:black.

Next time provide your code and be more specific, and of course, welcome :D